# How many elements will be there in a group so that it has $4$ subgroups of order $3$?

Tags: group-theory

I m thinking that a group of order $3$ will be of the form $\langle a \rangle=\{1,a,a^2=a^{-1} \}$, $ a^3=e$ therefore $a^2=a^{-1}$.
Therefore $\langle a \rangle=\{1,a,a^{-1} \}$.

Then there will be $3$ cyclic groups different then "$a$" ie "$b$", "$c$", "$d$" with no element same as any element of "$a$". So each group will have $2$ elements of order $3$. in total $4\cdot 2$ elements. Is this reasoning correct that all subgroups should be distinct?

Comment: You forgot the identlty, which has order $1$.

Comment: Is your question formulated correctly? Because there are infinitely many finite group with $4$ subgroups of order $3$.

Comment: Incidentally, after adding $1$ as per @lhf's comment, you have $9$ elements. Additionally, the order of the group (if finite) must be a multiple of $3$ here - which is already satisfied by $9$. After the obvious example of a group of order $9$ ($\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$), which does not have the desired property, maybe have a look at another group of order $9$, namely $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $S_4$ and $A_4$ have exactly $4$ subgroups of order $3$, the Sylow $3$-subgroups. So your conclusion that the group should have $8$ elements is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing this a bit: from the [proof](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi2taS-i_LpAhWrM-wKHZq7DFIQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.toronto.edu%2F%7Eyuvalf%2FMcKay%2520Another%2520Proof%2520of%2520Cauchy%2527s%2520Group%2520Theorem.pdf&usg=AOvVaw32U8G_pMHczA1LYp7-0GG1) (1959) of James McKay of Cauchy's Theorem (the existence of an element of prime power order $p$, if $p$ divides the order of $G$) it follows that $$\#\{g \in G: o(g)=p\} \equiv -1 \text{ mod }p$$

If there are $l$ subgroups of order $p$, then $l=1$ or any pair of different subgroups of order $p$ have trivial intersection (apply Lagrange's Theorem on the intersection, being a subgroup of each of the subgroups of order $p$).

Hence, leaving out the identity element, there are $l(p-1)$ elements of order $p$. Combining this with the above formula yields $$l \equiv 1 \text{ mod } p$$

So in your case taking $p=3$, the minimal number of subgroups of order $3$ in a group is $4$, the next possibility would be $7$, $10$, ... etc.. As Hagen pointed out $G=C_3 \times C_3$ is the minimal example, and you can produce very large examples by looking at $G \times S$, where $S$ is a group with $3 \nmid |S|$.